# How to send notifications using Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, events, notifications, queue

I have a website for jobs, the user can follow a company and then he will get notifications whenever theres a new job, so what I did is the following :

I created a model called JobNotification, whenever a company create new job, I create a job notification, I store the company_id, job_id and a generated text, so this job notification will be sent to the users,

what I did next is to create job called SendJobNotification, and dispatch it after the JobNotification creation, the SendJobNotification, will fetch the users that is following this company and insert user_id and job_notification_id, so when the user logged in again, he will see the notifications.

so the problem is, is theres any better way ? maybe using events ?
I dont want to use queue:listen in the server in order to run the queues, also the users fetching is taking so much time.
This is my SendJobNotification Job code:

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\AccountJobNotification;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use App\Account;
use App\JobNotification;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Company;
class SendJobNotification extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $notification;

    public function __construct(JobNotification $notification)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;

    }  
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $users = Company::find($this->notification->company_id)->followers()->get();
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            $job_notification = new AccountJobNotification();
            $job_notification->user_id = $user->id;
            $job_notification->job_notification_id = $this->notification->id;
            $job_notification->save();
        }


    }
}
```

Please notice, I am not making realtime notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it by using events and listeners.
I would do it this way:
In your controller, fire the event:

```
   Event::fire(new JobCreated($job));
```

Then add a event (JobCreated.php) and a listener (AddNotifications.php):
In your events folder create: JobCreated.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class JobCreated extends Event
{
    public function __construct($job)
    {
        $this->job_id=$job->id;
        $this->company_id=$job->company_id;
    }
}
```

In your listeners folder create Addnotifications.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\JobCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
class AddNotifications
{
    public function handle(JobCreated $event)
    {
        $company_id=$event->company_id;
        $job_id=$event->job_id;
        your handle code......
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include both in the EventServiceProvider.php inside the providers folder:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\JobCreated' => [
            'App\Listeners\AddNotifications'
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this queue-able ? will it solve the delay process ?

Answer (score 2):

@Ferran answer is correct. For add this event in a queue you have to implement ShouldQueue interface like below.

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Events;

    use App\Events\Event;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;


    class JobCreated extends Event implements ShouldQueue
    {
        public function __construct($job)
        {
            $this->job_id=$job->id;
            $this->company_id=$job->company_id;
        }
    }
```

And for run queue effectively. Use queue::work as and run it as daemon like below

```
php artisan queue:work connection-name --daemon
```

On linux architecture add "> /dev/null 2>&1" at end code command for run it without waiting.

```
php artisan queue:work beanstalkd --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

here beanstalkd is a queue driver Or you can use supervisor. Use following link for more information

[laravel5.2 run queue as daemon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#daemon-queue-listener)

Comment: Thank you, but I dont get it, where can I fetch the users, should I make job ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked for a method for sending this notifications that don't require a queue worker (which I think would be the right way to go, BTW), here's a way to do it using the Database Notifications.

You've already got answers with samples using Event Listener/Handlers, so here's a way to do it using native Eloquent events and a Service Provider.

> aside: the Service Provider isn't required, but I like to contain all
>   my model events in them so I don't pull my hair out checking through
>   models trying to find an errant created/deleted event

You'll need to do a little set up first:

```
php artisan make:provider JobListingServiceProvider
php artisan make:notification JobListingWasCreated
php artisan notifications:table
php artisan migrate
```

...and you'll need to edit your list of providers in `config/app.php` to include your new provider...

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\JobListingServiceProvider::class, //<-- New one
```

**JobListingServiceProvider** <-- The Service Provider

```
public function boot(){
    JobListing::created(function($listing){

        $newJobListing = new JobListingWasCreated($listing);
        $listing->company->followers()->orderBy('id')->chunk(50, function($users) use ($newJobListing){
            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                $user->notify($newJobListing);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I'm using `chunk()` there instead of `each()` because you could be dealing with potentially thousands of user records (as recommended by the docs) and there's an `orderBy('id')` in there because `chunk()` requires that your Builder have an `orderBy` clause in it.

**JobListingWasCreated** <-- The Notification

```
protected $listing;

public function __construct(JobListing $listing)
{
    $this->listing = $listing;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'listing_id' => $this->listing->id,
        'company_id' => $this->listing->company->id
    ];
}
```

Because we're listening for the Eloquent events, it'll be impossible to create a job listing without the notifications being "sent out" (which in this case means they're saved to the database, although again I recommend using the queue if you're going to be doing network transactions like sending emails or Slacks).

When adding a job listing to a company, it took my local machine ~3 seconds to create notifications for 1542 users. If that's too long for someone to wait to create a job listing, you're going to *have* to use queues. It'll take even longer per notified user if you use email or Slack.

Here's my database seeder code if you want to recreate similar conditions:

```
$users = factory(App\User::class, 10000)->create();
$companies = factory(App\Company::class, 300)->create();

$users->each(function($user) use($companies){
    $ids = $companies->random(rand(10, 80))->pluck('id')->all();
    $user->companies()->sync($ids); 
});
```

Also, my User/Company models for clarity:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
    }
}
```

---

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function addJobListing($listingTitle)
    {
        $this->jobListings()->save(
            new JobListing(['title' => $listingTitle])
        );
    }

    public function jobListings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(JobListing::class);
    }

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

...and the many-to-many pivot table between users and companies:

```
    Schema::create('company_user', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
    });
```